# Is there a way to map a character to another in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, keymapping

I use an alternative keyboard layout (Dvorak based [BÉPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%89PO) for french) for witch the easiest apostrophe to type is this one: `’`(U+2019), the one used in programmation `'` (U+0027) needs the combination with AltGr.

Is there a way in PyCharm to automatically map `’` (that is unused) to `'`?

Comment: you could use some third-party tools such as AutohotKey.

Comment: Thanks, but it is incompatible with my PyCharm version 2020.1, only 2019.3.3 and 2019.3.4 are supported.

Comment: xmodmap if you are in linux